# HiveQL - Joining on a column created on my Select Statement

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am trying to join two tables in Hive on multiple column. One of the columns I want to join on is a one where I am manipulating some data to match the structure in the other table and then I plan to join on it.

My challenge is that the column that I am creating will not allow me to join on it. I have tried a few different ways but I have been unsuccessful to this point.  Any help is appreciated!

```
SELECT 
prvdr_num, 
CONCAT(SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 5, 2),"/",SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 7, 
2),"/",SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 1, 4)) as Calendar_Admit_date,
AdmitDate,
CMSId
FROM table1
INNER JOIN  table2
ON table1.CMSId = table2_lds.prvdr_num
AND table1.AdmitDate = 
table2.CONCAT(SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 5, 2),"/",SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 7, 
2),"/",SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 1, 4))
```

I have also tried this and it will not work.

```
SELECT 
prvdr_num, 
CONCAT(SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 5, 2),"/",SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 7, 
2),"/",SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 1, 4)) as Calendar_Admit_date,
AdmitDate,
CMSId
FROM table1
INNER JOIN  table2
ON table1.CMSId = table2_lds.prvdr_num
AND table1.AdmitDate = 
table2.Calendar_Admit_date
```

Comment: Index should always be on the column names, like `tab1.a=concat(tab2.col1,tab2.col2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to cast your new column as a date on the join?

```
 SELECT 
    prvdr_num, 
    CONCAT(SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 5, 2),"/",SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 7, 
    2),"/",SUBSTR(CLM_ADMSN_DT, 1, 4)) as Calendar_Admit_date,
    AdmitDate,
    CMSId
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN  table2
    ON table1.CMSId = table2_lds.prvdr_num
    AND table1.AdmitDate = 
    cast(CONCAT(SUBSTR(table2.CLM_ADMSN_DT, 5, 2),"/",SUBSTR(table2.CLM_ADMSN_DT, 7, 
    2),"/",SUBSTR(table2.CLM_ADMSN_DT, 1, 4)) as date)
```

Comment: both of my date columns are stored as string right now.  I tried to CAST the CONCAT part as a string but still get the same error:SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid function 'inp_claims_lds.CONCAT

Comment: Where is this function coming from ? inp_claims_lds

Comment: sorry - inp_claims_lds is the name of my actual table2.  So the error I get would actually look like this: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid function 'table2.CONCAT'

Comment: You need to put the qualifier inside like this: CONCAT(SUBSTR(table2.CLM_ADMSN_DT, 5, 2) - updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: Daniel Marcus!  You solved it - thank you so much this was driving me nuts.  Much appreciate. You are a true hero.